# Term for the use of the same programming language in every tier?

Tags: terminology, programming-languages

What is the technical term that describes the use of the same programming language in every tier in the architecture of a system? For example, having JavaScript in model, view and controller.

edit #1: MVC was mentioned just to give an example. I read the concept in a book once when I was at the university but can't remember. I've been googling the concept but can't reach it. Thanks again

Comment: Why would you use different languages in MVC? Why does it matter to you how to call it? More popular is full stack usage of the same language, but currently only one language could be used that way, so there is also no need for terminology, full stack monolanguage programming is coined, though.

Comment: Mention MVC was just an example. It could be database + gui using the same language. I just want to know the name of the technical concept

Comment: Damn down-votes... they don't help me to be better :-/

Comment: Down vote is not mine, but I see the usage dispute (terminology tag is not popular one and description is not complete). I am sorry for this, but your example is a bit odd and if you have better one or general description, it would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I it is not widely used terminology, if you use MVC it makes little sense to deploy different languages, because some glue is needed to maintain it (say data sharing between different languages).

The term is monolanguage (monolingual programming) or homogeneous language programming. Similar terms like homogeneous programming are about same hardware used among nodes.
Term monolanguage or homogeneous programming environment is more popular with creating full stack of software based on the same language, which currently is only one.